# typeid(x).name() yields 'y', what does it mean?

Tags: c++, struct, types

In Code below, we get:
12 4
y
typeid().name should return data type,
but I cannot find which data type 'y' means

```
void alignment()
{
    struct Foo
    {
        int   i;
        float f;
        char  c;
    };

    std::cout << sizeof(Foo) << '\t' << alignof(Foo) << '\n';
    auto x = alignof(Foo);
    std::cout << typeid(x).name() << '\n';
}
```

I tried to find an association with data type names but nothing  fits

Comment: *typeid().name should return data type.* No, it should not, it's up to a compiler, its version, noon phase and so on.

Comment: The result of `typeid().name()` is implementation-defined.   Which, essentially, there are some constraints imposed by the standard but, within those constraints, the implementation can produce any string it likes.   Practically, there are not many constraints - there is no guarantee that two distinct types will have distinct names, there is no guarantee that the result will be a string that is comprehensible to a human.

Comment: @273K noon phase... so that depends if it happens before lunch or after lunch.

Comment: If you want a particular name association, you can make your own `std::unordered_map<std::type_info const*, std::string>` mapping.  Boost has done that with `#include <boost/type_index.hpp>` to get their `pretty_name()`, or `#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>` to get their demangled name of the `typeid(T).name()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried to find an association with data type names but nothing fits

Your compiler gave `std::size_t` name `y`, mine called it `m`, both are right and fully allowed to.
According to:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name

> Some implementations (such as MSVC, IBM, Oracle) produce a human-readable type name. Others, most notably gcc and clang, return the mangled name, which is specified by the Itanium C++ ABI. The mangled name can be converted to human-readable form using implementation-specific API such as abi::__cxa_demangle directly or through boost::core::demangle. It can also be piped through the command-line utility c++filt -t.

And `alignof` returns `size_t`, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof).

Example with demangling that using Boost:
https://godbolt.org/z/8959KdMhv

Comment: Actually, you both use compatible compilers, but `size_t` is alias of `unsigned long long` (aka `y`) on Windows and of `unsinged long` on linux (aka `m` by same spec). `typeid` returns name of aliased type.